# Getting error when trying to use OPENQUERY Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery

when i run this  query

```
SELECT *   
    FROM OPENQUERY([XXX], 'SELECT * FROM Database.Table WHERE (MBCONO=650) AND MBCUNO LIKE a%' )
```

Get the Error :

> OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "XXX" returned message
>   "Token %ÂŸFOR SKIP WITH FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT OPTIMIZE SQLSTATE:
>   42601, SQLCODE: -104".

Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 An error

> occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM Database.Table WHERE
>   (MBCONO=650) AND MBCUNO LIKE a%'" for execution against OLE DB
>   provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "LAWSON".

But when I run the Same query Without  `AND MBCUNO LIKE a%`  Return Result !!

Any One Can Help Me About This Issue

Thanx

Comment: when i do this 

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Comment: 3ala fekra ana mn de2e2a fakrt a3mel zayak , kol youm ba3d el sho3'al ha3mel keda .
belmonasba enta bteshta3'l eh ?

Comment: rabena m3ak ana ta2reban kont zayak mesh fe el magal bas fe tare2t el sho3'al w ba3d ta3b rabena waf2ny w safert , ya3ne ana now met3'arb hhhhhhhhh , sa3ba bas fe natega eny bat3lem w ba3mel most2bl  but fe masr enta betdya3 wa2t w ta3b w mafesh most2bal .

Comment: BEGAD FORSA SA3EDA AWE W EZA MOMKEN NETWASEL 3ALA SKYPE !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting escaped single quotes around the `LIKE` condition?

```
SELECT *   
    FROM OPENQUERY([XXX], 'SELECT * FROM Database.Table WHERE (MBCONO=650) AND MBCUNO LIKE ''a%''' )
```

If this doesn't work, try running the query directly against the target server.

Comment: Not Work :(  , i try the query in local server worked , but on linked server not working .